# I cant get the value from the second textbox in my tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter, input, textbox

I'm trying to program a very little app that should start with a window where you put a password, and that works. after that it opens another window and asks for credential that will go into a file (not developed yet!).
My problem is that I can't get the value from the second text widget in the second window. Can someone help me with that?

here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root=Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.title("password test")

def getNewWindow():
    root2 = tk.Tk()
    root2.geometry("200x200")
    root2.title("infos")
    textBox2=Text(root2, height=2, width=10)
    textBox2.pack()
    def retrieve_input2():
        inputValue2=textBox2.get("1.0","end-1c")
    if  inputValue2 == "110604":
        pass
    buttonCommit=Button(root2, height=1, width=10, text="Commit", 
                    command=lambda: retrieve_input2())
    buttonCommit.pack()
def retrieve_input():
    inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    if inputValue == "110604":
        getNewWindow()

textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()
buttonCommit=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Commit", 
                    command=lambda: retrieve_input())
#command=lambda: retrieve_input() >>> just means do this when i press the button
buttonCommit.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Useful tidbit: `lambda: funcname()` can be simplified to just `funcname`

Comment: Fix your indentation. `if inputValue2 == '110604':` needs to be inside `def retrieve_input2()`

Comment: Why are you opening a new window instead of just displaying the second textbox in the same window?

Comment: Is that indentation problem in the real code or just a copying error?

Comment: the indentation was a copying error.

Comment: i'll try to put everything under one page and i'll let you know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you know that you can't get the value? Have you tried to print inputValue2? If so, how did you tried?

Comment: Other than the indentation problem I don't see a problem.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference whether it's in one window or two windows. I just thought it was strange.

Comment: Also `root2 = tk.Tk()` should actually be `root2 = tk.Toplevel()`. In tkinter only the main window should be a Tk object

Comment: You say you can't get the data. Why can't you? What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: Do you realize `inputValue2` is defined on local scope? Hence is not available to use outside the function `retrieve_input2()`